# When the user is authenticate after few seconds identity redirect to login page but the session id remains in browser storage

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, identity

Here the identity class for authentication. it works fine on my localhost but it's behaving strange after deployment on server.I used OWIN for authentication, it works fine for first login, but after few seconds if I refresh the page, it redirects me back to the login page.

```
public class IdentityConfig
{
     public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<AppDBContext>(AppDBContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<AppUserManager>(AppUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<AppRoleManager>(AppRoleManager.Create);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<AppUserManager, AppUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => manager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie))
            },
            CookieName = "MyCookie",
            //CookieDomain = "www.example.com",
            //CookieHttpOnly = true,
            //CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always,
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(double.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["app:SessionTimeout"])),
            SlidingExpiration = true
        });
    }
}
```

Here the web.config code of [search4best](http://search4best.com/) used for session timeout

```
<add key="owin:AppStartup" value="Search4Best.App_Start.IdentityConfig" />
<add key="app:SessionTimeout" value="15"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on web.config try this

`<machineKeyvalidationKey="F18753F2CF84EFFFB10600B1E29D9849A74F080A1E1170BF728D8381979271EF6894673001C877FD8A349F8D953024019AF6C4C5090309B4569C1933ECC90D94"
decryptionKey="504430FBB7D426A3C401600906CD5C121DC0808B0D40328E02EAF7A59652157B"
validation="SHA1" decryption="AES"/>`